# Proving De Morgan's Law with Natural Deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

[image]

Here is my attempt, but I'm really not sure if I've done it right;
as I'm just about getting the hang of Natural Deduction technique.

Have I done it correctly? If not, where did I make errors and how should I do it?
Thank you in advance!
Sorry for the bad image quality; I'm bad at taking pictures.

Comment: I have found at least two mistakes (four actually, but two of them are repeated). And I suspect the whole thing might not be formally correct (even though you essentially got the process right) depending on a detail: what exactly is the meaning of $\equiv$?

Comment: @GitGud It's used when two propositional formulas are equivalent; where every truth-value assignment gives same result for both propositional formulas. Could you tell me which parts are mistakes? Thank you!

Comment: Then you can't give a formal proof of $\neg (p\land q)\equiv \neg p\lor \neg q$ because this is a meta-statement. Note that $\neg (p\land q)\leftrightarrow \neg p\lor \neg q$ and $\neg (p\land q)\equiv \neg p\lor \neg q$ are different kind of objects. I'm still trying to get a sense of the meaning of the symbols you're using before explaining exactly what I mean because I don't want to go into unnecessary details, that's why I'm being a little vague.

Comment: @GitGud Because of the soundness of Natural Deduction, to prove $\varphi\equiv\psi$ (i.e. $\varphi\vDash\psi$ and $\psi\vDash\varphi$), we can instead prove $\varphi\vdash\dashv\psi$.

Comment: @LoMaPh I know that. But asking for a formal proof of $\varphi\equiv \psi$ is simply non-sense.

Comment: @GitGud I know what you are saying. But there is no mention of a "formal proof" of $\varphi\equiv\psi$ in the question. To show that the relation $\varphi\equiv\psi$ holds, we just need to show $\varphi\vdash\dashv\psi$ holds (because of soundness), and we do this using Natural Deduction. What is wrong with this?

Comment: @LoMaPh Nothing wrong with that. But even though it isn't explicitly stated, the body of the question suggests the OP wants a formal a proof, I could be wrong. What is actually wrong is step $6$, the justification is not $\bot \text I$ (there's no way that's a badly written $\neg$) and it should be $\neg \neg p$. Same thing on step 10.

Comment: @GitGud You're right about lines 6 and 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the second part lines 2 and 7 are redundant, instead assume line 3.

Edit: As noticed by @GitGud, in the first part, line 6 must be $\neg\neg p \ (\neg I)$. So you need to add another line to get $p$ by $(\neg\neg E)$. Similar correction for line 10.

Comment: Oh, I see it. Thank you! Are other parts all fine?

Comment: They seem legit.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little uncomfortable with step 6 of part 2, i.e., using three steps (1,4,5) to assert a contradiction - seems like too much intuition for my liking. If possible, would like to limit myself to just the { φ ∧ ¬φ } form of contradiction. Minimal intuition - an object cannot be both itself and not itself at the same time.

Is the following possible instead? {n}, where n is a natural number, denotes underlying dependencies.

```
{1}    1. ¬P ∨ ¬Q              premise
{2}    2. P ∧ Q                assumption for proof by contradiction
{2}    3. P                    2 ∧E
{2}    4. Q                    2 ∧E
{5}    5. ¬P                   assumption, 1st disjunct of ¬P ∨ ¬Q
{2,5}  6. P ∧ ¬P               3,5 ∧I
{7}    7. ¬Q                   assumption, 2nd disjunct of ¬P ∨ ¬Q
{2,7}  8. Q ∧ ¬Q               4,7 ∧I
{1,2}  9. (P ∧ ¬P) ∨ (Q ∧ ¬Q)  1,5,6,7,8 Discharge 5,7   i.e. ⊥ 
{1}    10. ¬(P ∧ Q)            2,9 proof by contradiction, discharge 2
```

Since step 10 is an outcome of the premise alone, therefore (¬P ∨ ¬Q) ⊢ ¬(P ∧ Q).

11 Feb:
Just an additional comment after some thought. Citing steps 1 (¬P ∨ ¬Q), 4(P) and 6(Q) to justify a contradiction is implicitly claiming that (¬P ∨ ¬Q) is in contradiction with (P ∧ Q) (i.e. conjunction of steps 4 and 6). But this contradiction is the very thing we're trying to prove. That's why I wasn't comfortable previously. Glad for comments/correction if any. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue that @Wei brought up appears the most critical.  Here is [a proof](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) imitating the script as much as possible:

[image]

The blue boxes on lines 6 and 10 show that the justification would be indirect proof (IP) not negation introduction. @LoMaPh offers a different suggestion for fixing that.

As LoMaPh points out one could skip lines 16 and 25, but it is not incorrect to leave them as they are.

The issue @Wei brought up is critical and is fixed in the red box. One needs to explicitly do a disjunction elimination on both disjuncts in line 15.