# Simple Fitch proof of De Morgan law

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

Can someone tell me how to prove $\neg( \wedge )$ given the premise $\neg  \vee \neg $ using Fitch system?

I was trying to do something like [Proving De Morgan's Law with Natural Deduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166174/proving-de-morgans-law-with-natural-deduction) but my teacher said that this is too complicated and I shouldn't use proof by contradiction.

I should use Or Elimination at the highest level and there should be about 20 steps.
Do you have any ideas or hints? I've been struggling on this for a long time :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but I would like to try my hand on this problem.
Here's my version

$$
\begin{array}{l|llll:l}
1. & \neg p \vee \neg q & & & & \text{Premise} \\\hline
2. & & p \wedge q & & & \text{Assumption} \\\hline
3. & & p & & & \text{And Elimination: 2} \\
4. & & q & & & \text{And Elimination: 2} \\
5. & (p \wedge q) \rightarrow q & & & & \text{Implication Introduction: 2, 4}\\
6. & & p \wedge q & & & \text{Assumption} \\\hline
7. & & & \neg q & & \text{Assumption} \\\hline
8. & & \neg q \rightarrow \neg q & & & \text{Implication Introduction: 7, 7} \\
9. & & & \neg p & & \text{Assumption} \\ \hline
10. & & & & q & \text{Assumption} \\\hline
11. & & & & p \wedge q & \text{Reiteration: 6} \\
12. & & & & p & \text{And Elimination: 11} \\
13. & & & q \rightarrow p & & \text{Implication Introduction: 10, 12}\\
14. & & & & q & \text{Assumption} \\\hline
15. & & & & \neg p & \text{Reiteration: 9} \\
16. & & & q \rightarrow \neg p & & \text{Implication Introduction: 14, 15} \\
17. & & & \neg q & & \text{Negation Introduction: 13, 16} \\
18. & & \neg p \rightarrow \neg q & & & \text{Implication Introduction: 9, 17} \\
19. & & \neg p \vee \neg q & & & \text{Reiteration: 1} \\
20. & & \neg q & & & \text{Or Elimination: 19, 18, 8} \\
21. & (p \wedge q) \rightarrow \neg q & & & & \text{Implication Introduction: 6, 20}\\
22. & \neg(p \wedge q) & & & & \text{Negation Introduction: 5, 21} \\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any way to avoid Proof by Contradiction in order to prove this in Fitch.

And sure, you can start with $\lor$ Elimination: one subproof for $\neg p$, and another for $\neg q$.  However, since in both cases you are trying to get to $\neg (p \land q)$, you'll want Proof by Contradiction inside each of those subproofs: Assume $p \land q$, and get a contradiction.  The good news is that each of these can be completed pretty fast (I'll leave the missing steps to you):

[image]

Maybe your teacher meant:  don't do a Proof by Contradiction at the top level ... and the above approach avoids doing exactly that ... but my question is: why not do a Proof by Contradiction at the top level?!  That should work just as well and just as efficiently: Assume $p \land q$ on the outset, and then do the two subproofs for the $\lor$ Elim on $\neg p \lor \neg q$ inside of that ... but the rest is exactly the same. In fact, this proof ends up being two lines shorter:

[image]

Comment: The only on reason is that we didn't study Proof by Contradiction yet :) We can introduce or eliminate only 5 things: Or, And, Negation, Implication and Biconditional. It feels like there should be an easy answer

Comment: @Dezmond I don;t know how your Fitch rules are defined, but in my version of Fitch, $\neg$ Intro *is* the formalization of Proof by Contradiciton. Note how on line 10 of the second proof, for example, I apply $\neg$ Intro, and it's clearly Proof by Contradiction: from the fact that the assumption of $p \land q$ leads to a contradiction you conclude $\neg (p \land q)$.  And again, I see no way to prove this without the use of $\neg$ Intro

Comment: I've seen the term "Proof by Contradiction" applied to two distinct rules: one is $\lnot I$; and the other is what https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/ refers to as "$IP$".  (The distinction becomes especially important if you study intuitionistic logic, where $\lnot I$ is perfectly valid but $IP$ is rejected.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Agreed, there are several versions of "Proof by Contradiction", and the difference can be important. Still, I don't see how to prove this argument without using *some* version of 'Proof by Contradiction'